# Where is Avast 2016 deleted files log?

Tags: avast

I installed Avast, hoping it was going to give less false positives.

It promptly concludes that half of my coding tools, custom programs, whatnot are "Virus-Gen" or "Malware-Gen" and other heuristics and nuke half of my system.

Of course, I want to uninstall it, but I want to know first what exactly damage it did, but I can't find the log files, searching on google only led me to outdated information, Avast 2016 seemly is quite different from past versions.

Where is the log of the files Avast deleted?

Comment: it's not in `%programdata%\avast software\avast\log` or `%programdata%\avast software\avast\report`?

Comment: Oh, it is on the "report" folder thing. PLease create a answer with it so I can accept it :) I am sure more people have the same question (I found this question on lots and lots of sites, but always with the "log" folder answer... leading to wild goose chase of reading 20 log files to figure what one was correct, and not being any of them)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logs that Avast 2016 in regards to actions it takes on files such as deleting, quarantining, cleaning & etc make are stored in the following directory:

```
%programdata%\avast software\avast\report
```

Logs that pertain to the operation of the Avast software such as updates can be found here:

```
%programdata%\avast software\avast\log
```

You can access either of these folders easily by using <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and copy and pasting one of the paths from above and clicking `OK` or pressing the <kbd>Enter/Return</kbd> key.

Comment: just making a clarification for this awnser, after reading every single log file... Avast saves in "report" folder, only the logs I actually wanted, that is the actions taken on your system (moving files, deleting, "repairing" them to remove viruses, etc...), while the "log" folder has all other internal logs of Avast itself (updates, crashes, open and closed handles, etc...)

Comment: @speeder I've updated that, thanks for letting me know!